# android open sharedPreference xml file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After understanding how sharedPreferences works, I create an xml file at /data/data/com.your.package.name/shared_prefs/prefs.xml. However, using eclipse's file explorer I am able to find it but not to open it to see its content. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file explorer there is button pull file from device, first select the file and then click on that button it will save the file on to a location from where you can access the file. attached is the screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in ddms>file Explorer>data>data>your app package name>shared_prefs>your_file.xml

select your file then click on pull file from device at the time saving save file with xml extension and you will get preferences file

Comment: this path is accessible only when android phone is rooted.