# Android: get the key of sharedpreferences having its value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, key-value

I have the value of an item in Android `SharedPreferences` and I want to get its key. I am not able to figure it out. Any idea please?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499715/android-open-sharedpreference-xml-file

Comment: I want to do it programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` `getAll()` to obtain a map of all key-value pairs and iterate its `entrySet()` looking for the value-key pair you are after.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences  getAll(). method  will return  Maps of key Value pair, now  filter out  the key from the value.

Answer (score 1):

you can use getAll() function which return Map

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()

Map has method getKeySet()

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#keySet()

you can get keys

Answer (score 0):

If keys are guaranteed to be unique in SharedPreferences use this method, because it will only return the key for the first matching value.

```
private String getSharedKeyByValue(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String value) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : sharedPreferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null; // Not Found
}
```